# How do I tell jQuery to get a element's value attribute on load?

Tags: jquery

I am inserting a username into div content like so with a templating engine:

```
<div class="username" value="#{user}"></div>
```

How do I tell jQuery to get the contents of `value` when the page loads?

Comment: This is super-basic stuff. Have you read any of the jQuery documentation?

Comment: Are you invoking this in the document load handler, or just directly in the script tag?

Comment: What prompted this question is `$('.username').attr('value')` was not working for me. This was due to a typo in the method calling this code however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `attr` property

```
   $('.username').attr('value')
```

Also remember that `value` is not a default property of a div. So for such cases it is a better idea to use **HTML-5 data-* attributes** .

Which are prefixed by `data-` which pertain that those are custom attributes.

So this is a better convention

```
<div class="username" data-value="#{user}"></div>
```

---

And to access it you would using `.data()`  method

```
$('.username').data('value')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you used class and not id I will assume you have more than one username in the DOM, so will select one of them and grab its value attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var username = $(".username")[0].getAttribute("value");
});
```

Comment: You don't need `[0]` there. It is implied with `val()`.

Comment: Div does not support the value property. Only form elements value can be accessed using `val`

Comment: Even this won't work. Accessing it by index gives you a `DOM` object . And `DOM` objects do not have a method called `.attr`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var usernameValue = $(".username").attr("value");
    alert(usernameValue); // or however you would like to use this variable.
});
```